# How to close the connection from an Isapi filter?

Tags: winapi, iis, iis-7, iis-8, isapi

I Would like from inside an **ISAPI filter** (so from inside the function `HttpFilterProc`) to drop the connection with the client (This is important to avoid to download all the data in the request). Under an isapi I can do like this :

```
  if not ECB.ServerSupportFunction(ECB.ConnID,
                                   HSE_REQ_CLOSE_CONNECTION,
                                   nil,
                                   nil,
                                   nil) then raiseLastOsError;
```

But i didn't find a way to do it from inside an ISAPI function

Comment: @rbMn : As i see i can call HSE_REQ_CLOSE_CONNECTION  from inside an isapi extension but not from inside an ISAPIFilter :( i didn't fund any equivalent

Comment: sorry. not note that you want do this from **filter**. confuse it with **extension**